# No Math Symbols appearing

Tags: symbols, memoir

In my tex file, =  doesn't appear.

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu]{nag}        
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside
  \ifodd\c@page \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}%
  \newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany,leqno,footinclude=true]{memoir} 
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
%\usepackage{amsmath,fontspec}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\def\cftchapteraftersnum{.}
\makeatletter
\def\@copyrightspace{\relax}
\makeatother

\settrimmedsize{297mm}{210mm}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt} 
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth} 
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth} 
\settypeblocksize{634pt}{448.13pt}{*} 
\setulmargins{4 cm}{*}{*} 
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5} 
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{51pt}{\onelineskip} 
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip} 
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*} 
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout
\pagestyle {plain}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}
\OnehalfSpacing 

\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{\newpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}

\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{underscore}     
% Add other packages needed for chapters here. For example:
\usepackage{lipsum}                 %Needed to create dummy text
\usepackage{amsfonts}                   %Calls Amer. Math. Soc. (AMS) fonts
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}            %Writes maths centred down
\usepackage{stmaryrd}                   %New AMS symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}                    %Calls AMS symbols
\usepackage{amsthm}                 %Calls AMS theorem environment
\usepackage{newlfont}                   %Helpful package for fonts and symbols
\usepackage{layouts}                    %Layout diagrams
\usepackage{graphicx}                   %Calls figure environment
\usepackage{longtable,rotating}         %Long tab environments including rotation. 
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}         %Needed to encode non-english characters 
                                    %directly for mac
\usepackage{colortbl}                   %Makes coloured tables
\usepackage{wasysym}                    %More math symbols
\usepackage{mathrsfs}                   %Even more math symbols
\usepackage{float}                      %Helps to place figures, tables, etc. 
\usepackage{verbatim}                   %Permits pre-formated text insertion
\usepackage{upgreek }                   %Calls other kind of greek alphabet
\usepackage{latexsym}                   %Extra symbols
\usepackage[square,numbers,
             sort&compress]{natbib}     %Calls bibliography commands 
\usepackage{url}                        %Supports url commands
\usepackage{etex}                       %eTeXÕs extended support for counters
\usepackage{fixltx2e}                   %Eliminates some in felicities of the 
                                    %original LaTeX kernel
\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel}     %For languages characters and hyphenation
\usepackage{color}                                  %Creates coloured text and background
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
             allcolors=black]{hyperref}              %Creates hyperlinks in cross references
\usepackage{memhfixc}                   %Must be used on memoir document 
                                    %class after hyperref
\usepackage{enumerate}                  %For enumeration counter
\usepackage{footnote}                   %For footnotes
\usepackage{microtype}                  %Makes pdf look better.
\usepackage{rotfloat}                   %For rotating and float environments as tables, 
                                    %figures, etc. 
\usepackage{alltt}                      %LaTeX commands are not disabled in 
                                    %verbatim-like environment
\usepackage[version=0.96]{pgf}          %PGF/TikZ is a tandem of languages for producing vector graphics from a 
\usepackage{tikz}                       %geometric/algebraic description.
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,
               automata,backgrounds,
               petri,topaths}               %To use diverse features from tikz      


%
\usepackage{mathptmx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\usepackage{tocloft}%
\newcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
\begin{document}
% -----------------------------------------------------------Pages
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\input{frontmatter/title}

\end{document}
```

The above contains the preamble.

Consider putting in title.tex:

```
\[dupthresh = D\cdot[1+log(n)]\]
```

= does not appear.

A minimal example would be as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
$a=b$
\end{document}
```

Comment: why specify `\usepackage{enumitem}` three times (and `enumerate` which is incompatible with that)

Comment: you have posted a very long code section which no one can run as it references `\input{frontmatter/title}` that we don't have, and it has no examples of math which is the subject of the question? Please fix the example to be an example of the problem, preferably removing all lines that are unrelated.

Comment: You load ten (!) different packages for math symbols.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, i should clear that. Anyways, I can't idenify my problem, please help.

Comment: @ferrer You could easily isolate your problem by creating a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Given that no `=` symbol appears to be present in the code you've posted, it's not possible to diagnose the situation properly, let alone propose a remedy.

Comment: @Mico plz see the edit. titl.tex just has that equation.

Comment: @ferrer first you should make it reasonable for anyone to try to help by **posting an example of the problem** also don't load `etex` or `fixltx2e` in current latex releases and `newlfont` in any latex since the 1990's.

Comment: Here's a correct MWE: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
$x=x$
\end{document}`

Comment: It is always best for a new document to start with loading **no** packages and then just add packages if you need them. It is clear from this preamble that it just loads multiple packages multiple times, so such clashes are not unexpected.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I put the equation. There is no = sign appearing.

Comment: just don't load both fourierenc and mathptm. Also are you _really_ using a legacy apple encoding rather than a standard encoding `\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} ` ? (and why is `graphicx` loaded three times (none of which is needed as it is loaded by rotating`)?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, that solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The particular error is that the document loads two incompatible redefinitions of math mode, `fouriernc` and `mathptmx` but more generally the preamble loads *multiple* packages many of them three or four times, and most of them unneeded as the already extensive `memoir` class is used as base. It also loads `newlfont`, `etex`, `fixltx2e` which shouldn't be used with current releases. (`newlfont` should only ever have been used to work with documents from before latex2e was released in 1993). The preamble also defined `\cleardoublepage` twice, with different definitions, and specifies `\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}` which is unlikely to be the encoding used by modern text editors, even on a Mac.

My recommendation would be to change the document to start

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
```

then only add more packages if you need them.